# What is known about the Doctor's childhood?

Tags: doctor-who

What is known about the Doctor's childhood, or at least the time before the classic series? There's some stuff about him being half human, some stuff about a different universe Doctor, some about his history is always changing and some is about him being a loom. I know extended canon sometimes clashes but still, is there any definite canon?

(Please try to avoid spoilers from after “End of Time”.)

Comment: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor

Comment: "Definite canon" are not words that can be applied to *Doctor Who*.

Comment: Answering this question would spoil something that happened way after The End Of Time. When you get to series 8 (Capaldi's first) you'll see an episode with a child Doctor.

Comment: There was definitely a barn involved at some point.

Comment: Firstly, when has the doctor ever been references as being partly human? He's taken the form of a human as a disguise, and there is a clone of him that is part human, but afaik the doctor is 100% timelord. Secondly, I don't think it appropriate to ask us to limit an answer to a specific period of episodes so we don't spoil it for you. If you think it might be explained in a newer episode, *watch them for yourself*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no answer to your question fitting your criteria.  There was an episode *Listen* that occurred outside of your criteria that showed a child Doctor

It has been stated on occasion (I believe within your criteria), that the Doctor looked into the Infinite Schism as a child, went to the Time Lord Academy (for centuries), was nicknamed Sigma Theta at one point.

That is all that I can remember, as I haven't actually watched pre-revival episodes of *Doctor Who*

PS: More data about this question can be obtained by widening the criteria to include all of Capaldi's era

Answer (score 0):

Speaking ONLY from the original 7 doctors...

- In the final key to time story he meets drax, a chum from school days. He calls baker "feet" (from "feeta sigma").
- In the thing in the pit doctor says he was born under sign of "crossed computers" the gallifrean maternity service symbol.
- Heres one VERY few people catch; in the brain of morbius the doc fights him at "mind bending" and each timelord reveals the sequence of his lives on the monitor. And guess what? THERES A GUY BEFORE HARTNELL!